# How to make flexbox 'justify-content: space-between' have effect?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to create  following layout, where a header (green) spans the full width of the screen and is made up of two elements:

- a picture (pink), that is top-left aligned, and has the height of the next element
- a text block (red), that is top-right aligned. It  made of two stacked elements: a text div (yellow) and a button. The width button equals the text width.

The expected output is this:
[image]

My code is the following:

```css
          .header{
            background-color: green; 
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: flex-start;
          }
          .flex-element{
            display: inline-block;
          }
          .picture_container{
            background-color: pink
          }
          .picture{
            height: 100%;
          }
          .text_container{
            background-color: red
          }
          .text{
            background-color: yellow;
          }
```

```html
        <div class="header">
          <div class="flex-element picture_container">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/55/Tux_Enhanced.svg/154px-Tux_Enhanced.svg.png" alt="" class="picture">
          </div>
          <div class="flex-element text_container">
            <div class="text">
              AAAAAAAAAA <br>
              BBB
            </div>
            <button type="button" name="button" style="width: 100%">foo</button>
          </div>
        </div>
```

and gives following output:

[image]

The problem is that there is no "space-between" the pink and the red block, and they are not top aligned. I know I could work around it using css grid, yet I'd like to know why it isn't working.

**Question:** How to make `justify-content: space-between` have any effect?

Comment: Which browser are you using? Tried your code in Chrome and it works fine.

Comment: @Goombah Firefox Developer Edition 63.0b14 (64-bit)

Comment: @scraaappy: thanks for creating the snippet. I can see there that the code is working.

Comment: @Goombah: You made me solved the problem: adding `display: -moz-box;` in `.header{…}` resolved the issue.

Comment: i think you want a margin-left: auto on the right element of your flexbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a *browser issue*. Indeed, I am using ***Firefox*** Developer Edition 63.0b14 as a browser.

A hack was then to add `display: -moz-box;` in the `.header` css definition. It is strange, though, as *"Prefixed property values (such as -moz-box) are no longer needed for flexbox to work in major browsers."* (see [Michael_B's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52830947/how-to-make-flexbox-justify-content-space-between-have-effect/52831184?noredirect=1#comment92583900_52831184)). **A less hacky solution would hence be still appreciated.**

Full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <style media="screen">
      .header{
        background-color: green; 
        display: -moz-box;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: flex-start;
      }
      .flex-element{
        display: inline-block;
      }
      .picture_container{
        background-color: pink
      }
      .picture{
        height: 100%;
      }
      .text_container{
        background-color: red
      }
      .text{
        background-color: yellow;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <div class="flex-element picture_container">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/55/Tux_Enhanced.svg/154px-Tux_Enhanced.svg.png" alt="" class="picture">
      </div>
      <div class="flex-element text_container">
        <div class="text">
          AAAAAAAAAA <br>
          BBB
        </div>
        <button type="button" name="button" style="width: 100%">foo</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Prefixed property values (such as `-moz-box`) are no longer needed for flexbox to work in major browsers. Whatever the reason your code wasn't working, adding `display: -moz-box` is just a hack that happens to work in this one instance. It's not a reliable solution. In other words, the underlying problem you were facing was not addressed.

Comment: @Michael_B Indeed, it struck me that I had to use prefixes in 2018 with an up-to-date browser (maybe it's why I didn't think of the solution by myself). I welcome any suggestion if you have. Thank you for highlighting that it *shouldn't* be needed.

Comment: I didn't mention any alternative solutions because I tested your code in FF and could not reproduce the problem. I have it rendering the same as in Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

Please try below code

```
<style>
.header {
  padding: 10px;
}
.picture {
  width: auto;
}
.text_container {
  margin: auto 0;
}
.picture_container {
  display: block;
}
</style>
```